# BeautifulSoup web table scraping

Tags: python-2.7, screen-scraping

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
site = 'https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/racing/LocalResults.aspx/'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
res = urlopen(req)
rawpage = res.read()
page = rawpage.replace("<!-->", "")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"f_tac table_bd draggable"})
print (table)
```

this work perfectly got a table output, untill i change the url to next page there is nothing to output (None)

'https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2020/03/14&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=2'

please help what's wrong of the url or the code?

Answer (score 0):

you must add query string to end of url:

example:
to fetch table from page 2:

```
site ='https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/racing/LocalResults.aspx/?RaceDate=2020/03/14&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=2'
```